# Getting some garbage text when tar-ing a file

Tags: command-line, tar

when I run the following command:

```
tar -c music.tar iTunes\ Music/
```

But I get the following garbage output.                                                                                               b����n5���z��ԊV_o�P�O3|�b���i�Pl�jH��8��z5����ڕ?~D|_($�|b��:���š`�s7
�%z\��Jj����K����Z��V�)�A4
                             2��}�4�(�?#�P��ykX
                                                 �Q�e<�w�U����Y�8n��s�  1B��F.f�
�X9Lb=8��@����|�h�d�ǲ�I��L�]������-����gx��l囧���n�cs{f���f���6�M(�u��6��|pX�nH�V���$�ь�����7��n�H���Yua��Xn�;{�JP�����7�@R�f_旾j�*����3M�z�s9���"��0�$1�ɂ7:w�������|D_�����EjtO��߉�����PޘY�-�    xVF���Uwky�u�Yt�h ���K
                                                                                   �nJh�]K�J-�2��#Q̬���~�~B)OޑMĤ��
                                                                                                                  "��6#�Q,uNG�~��4t�>=^C

I don't really care if I'm just missing some font library. But I haven't run this to completion because...well i'm not really sure what it's doing.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use -cf, otherwise it just dumps the output to stdout (the window), which is exactly what you're seeing. You would use -c alone to pipe it to another program (though you can use > file.tar).